# Font pairing for Caslon

Tags: typefaces, font-pairing

I'm tinkering with a small booklet that contains an ancient Buddhist sutta text and modern commentary, interweaved in a form of reading monologue: some sutta text, some commentary, more sutta text, and so forth.

For the sutta text I thought to use Caslon ([link](http://www.myfonts.com/person/William_Caslon_I/)) but can't quite come up with a font for the modern commentary.  Something light and sans-serif, perhaps, even italic?

If not Caslon and a light sans-serif, then what other pairings would make sense?  Somehow I'm not drawn to using normal/bold combination of the same font though.

**EDIT** After I've accepted Andrew Leach's answer, I started poking around FontShop for a while.  I quite like the proposal of using the same family in serif/sans, and for example Milo ([link](http://www.fontshop.com/search/?q=ff%20milo)) seems to make for a legible reading type.  The old sutta text set in Milo Serif Medium:

[image]

and descriptive commentary in the lighter and more modern looking Milo Light Italic:

[image]

In that case, should I use size variations of Milo Light Italic for headings?  There won't be any more than chapter headings.  What about table of content, and opening pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems with Caslon is that it's very old-fashioned. That is obviously what has attracted you to using it, but its age and the style of the time is that the tracking is naturally quite wide:

[image: Caslon]

When trying to get a sans to go with that, which is a good idea, you need to consider the letter-shapes (like the high cross-bar on **e** and the upward slope of the bowl of **a** and perhaps the little tail of **u**):

[image: Rosemary Samuels]

But you also need to consider x-height (this sans is too great) and although the overall width here is similar, each letter is wider and natural tracking is reduced. It may be possible to use a font like this — this is [Rosemary Samuels](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/samuelstype/rosemary-samuels/) — and tweak its metrics so that the letters are slightly narrower and they are spaced a little further apart.

Pehaps something like [Linotype Projekt](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/projekt/) would do, although this doesn't appear to come in a lighter weight than this, which may need a heavier version of Caslon.

[image: Linotype Projekt]

On the other hand, if you can discount Caslon, there are a number of families which are available in both serif and sans form: those are bound to match. These are a couple of my favourites:

[Scala](http://www.myfonts.com/search/scala/fonts/):

[image: Scala]
[image: Scala Sans]

[Calluna](http://www.myfonts.com/search/calluna/fonts/):

[image: Calluna]
[image: Calluna Sans]

<sub>All images from [MyFonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you Andrew! If I was to use, say, Caluna, in both serif and sans-serif form, is the visual distinction visible enough?  It may be less strenuous to read when it comes from the same font family. Hmm..

Comment: Calluna comes in a lot of weights. You might use Calluna Sans Light, for example.

Comment: Hmm.. a Scala Sans Light (maybe italic) and a Serif Regular. That might work nicely, I'll play around with that. Perhaps a more general question: if a font misses a certain glyph, should I just contact the foundry?

Comment: @Jens No harm in asking! I don't think Scala is too bad though.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Lato** http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lato

[image]

Or **Carto Gothic**

[image]

Or **District Pro Thin** https://philsfonts.com/dl/district_thin_pro.zip

[image]

Or **Lane** http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/lab/k_m.htm

[image]

Comment: ...you mean to pair, or for headings?  Or both?

Comment: T would use the first two as headings i.e. if i want to have two different styles of headings, then **Caslon** + **any of these**.
And the rest for the description.